# How to sell subscriptions with Django?

Tags: django, subscription

I have to develop an application for selling web-services. I have 2 goals:

1) Any customer can subscribe to a service and using within a month having paid for it.

2) Any customer can pay for a e-content and study it unlimited time.

**Are there external libraries for Django to do it?**

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com).  They go at great length to help you find what you need, including a [section on e-commerce](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/ecommerce/) applications.  If it exists and it's open source, chances are it's there!